# JSON path how to get value of @

Tags: jsonpath

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"code": 201,
"data": {
    "type": "Agent",
    "id": {
        "@type": "Client",
        "@id": "88",
        "title": "Ing.",
        "titleAfter": null,
        "name": "Ján",
        "surname": "Kašperan",
        "idNumber": "8706229411",
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "idCardNumber": "OP12345",
        "idCardExpirationDate": null,
        "idCardType": {
            "@type": "IdCardType",
            "@id": 1,
            "name": "id_card_type.id_card",
            "shortName": "OP"
        },
        "type": 1
    }
}
}
```

I would like to write a JSON path expression so that I want to get the value of **"@id"**: "88",.

My JSON path do not work: $.data.id.@id

Comment: without too much more information - assuming that the first part of your expression is correct, have you tried `$.data.id["@id"]` - switching to bracket notation for that last part?

Comment: $.['data']['id']['@id']

Answer (score 0):

Since `@` is not allowed, access it by the string property name. More information about property accessors can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
var json = {
  "code": 201,
  "data": {
    "type": "Agent",
    "id": {
      "@type": "Client",
      "@id": "88",
      "title": "Ing.",
      "titleAfter": null,
      "name": "Ján",
      "surname": "Kašperan",
      "idNumber": "8706229411",
      "dateOfBirth": null,
      "idCardNumber": "OP12345",
      "idCardExpirationDate": null,
      "idCardType": {
        "@type": "IdCardType",
        "@id": 1,
        "name": "id_card_type.id_card",
        "shortName": "OP"
      },
      "type": 1
    }
  }
}
console.log(json.data.id["@id"])
```